# Should I sign up for Kettlebell classes?

Tags: weights, freeweights, kettlebell

I've been using a 35-lb kettlebell for about a month doing swings and turkish getups as described in 'Enter the Kettlebell's program minimum. I'm 5'9", 155lbs, and in decent shape.

I haven't really been feeling like I'm getting a worthwhile workout - maybe a little soreness the next day, but nothing like circuit training or road biking. My question is, would joining a kettlebell class (and learning better form) make the workouts more effective, or should I go up to the next size kettlebell?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend a kettlebell class or a personal trainer - depending on your needs.  The kettlebell is a tool like any other workout equipment.  The idea is to incorporate it within your current program (if you have one) and ensure the program is in tune with your goals (if you have those set).  Feeling 'sore' the next day is a good sign that you're working, but does not indicate that your are/are-not using proper technique or if your workout is well rounded.

So, direct to your question, yes, I would recommend signing up for a class, it will help define/refine your technique and give you motivation and new workout ideas.

Answer (score 1):

What are you looking for in a workout?

If you are looking for health, you should already be getting that from Swings an Get-Ups. Swings are one of the best things you can do your posterior chain and your back, get-ups are possibly the healthiest full-body movement you can do. Physical therapists love get-ups (those who know them). Of course you have to do them properly, so getting you form checked may still be a good idea. Also, get-up technique has been refined significantly since ETK came out. Check with "Kettlebells from the ground up", your local RKC or possibly youtube.

If you're looking for cardio, you can either work your way up to high rep swings, which are excellent cardio all by themselves, or you can just learn more exercises with kettlebells. The full ETK program is much more intense than ETK's program minimum.

A complex of clean&presses, swings, maybe snatches, pull-ups and push-ups will have you collapse on the floor in no time. But put the kettelbell down safely first.

Considering Swings, you might try to go hardstyle and work on your hip-drive. At the top of the movement, you should drive your hips forward as hard as you can (with your glutes) and contract your abs hard, your body should be completely stiff.

Comment: Could you please explain bit more about breathing technique when do Swings and "you should drive your hips forward as hard as you can (with your glutes) and contract your abs hard, your body should be completely stiff." I know I do drive from hips but not sure about how it helps by tightening abs and glutes